# Haskell: SortBy with multiple parameters (Birth dates)

Tags: sorting, haskell

I'm trying to sort a list of Birth dates according to Y > M > D priorities using sortBy.

Since nesting guards isn't possible, I've come up with this kind of ugly solution:

```
sortBD (day1, month1, year1) (day2, month2, year2)
  | year1 < year2 = GT
  | year1 < year2 = LT   -- Typo: < should be >
  | year1 == year2 = if compare month1 month2 == EQ then compare day1 day2 else compare month1 month2
```

This however returns an Exception due to non exhaustive patterns.

[EDIT]: To save others running into issues with the same problem the confusion: The problem in the code above is a typo, as pointed out in answers, not the approach itself.

Comment: typo? you have "<" on the first and second line.

Comment: Indeed. I'm confused how I managed to let that one slip... Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't covered the `year1 > year2` case, because you have a typo on this line:

```
  | year1 < year2 = GT
```

Instead of trying to carefully juggle `EQ`s and non-`EQ`s, you can just use the `Monoid` instance for `Ordering` to combine results:

```
sortBD (d1, m1, y1) (d2, m2, y2)
    = compare y1 y2
   <> compare m1 m2
   <> compare d1 d2
```

Even better still, the tuple instance already does this, so you can just reuse that:

```
sortBD (d1, m1, y1) (d2, m2, y2) = compare (y1, m1, d1) (y2, m2, d2)
```

Comment: I ended up not spotting the typo and rewriting everything using something close the tuple approach you pointed out.

Comment: @Elmex80s `sortBy` consumes `Ordering`s, and using `compare` (rather than `<=`) is the idiomatic way to produce an `Ordering`.

Comment: @Elmex80s No: as observed in my answer, he is storing the tuples in "reverse order" (day-month-year instead of year-month-day) compared to what he would need to get the sort order he wants from plain old `sort`.